# Ignition.ignite returns "Grid instance was not properly started or was already stopped"

Tags: java, scala, ignite

I have a two node Apache Ignite cluster up but when I call `Ignition.ignite` from the scala shell or a java program running on any of the machines I get:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteIllegalStateException: Grid instance was not properly started or was already stopped: null
```

I have tried naming the cluster in `default-config.xml`:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="gridName" value="grid"/>
</bean>
```

but that didn't work. The nodes were started using `ignite.sh` and can see that they started OK.

```
Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=2.0GB]
```

The only thing that worked for me is to use `Ignition.start([default-config.xml])` and then `Ignition.ignite("grid")` works; but now I have a second instance running on my machine:

```
Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=3, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=2.2GB]
```

Is `Ignition.ignite` bugged or is there something more I need to do to get it to work?

I am using `apache-ignite-fabric-1.4.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client application also needs to start a node. It will join the topology and provide the connectivity with the cluster. Most likely you don't want this node to store any data or execute jobs. If this is the case, start it in client mode:

```
Ignition.setClientMode(true);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(..);
```

After this you should see this topology snapshot (note that there are still 2 servers, but 1 client is added:

```
Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=2, clients=1, CPUs=8, heap=2.2GB]
```

`Ignition.ignite()` method can be used to get a reference to the instance that was already started. If it's not started yet, `IllegalStateException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I use ignite-core:1.4.0 and I have no problems in starting ignite with

```
IgnitionEx.start(igniteConfigurationAdapter);
```

where igniteConfigurationAdapter is just a IgniteConfiguration instance where you specify what type of node you want to create.

Maybe you did no specified the node type in your IgniteConfiguration instance

Comment: I already have two nodes up, what you suggest there creates a new node. I want to connect to my already running two nodes and the documentation says that I should do this with Ignition.ignite() or Ignition.ignite(String name) but it is throwing the error described above.

Comment: ok, I provide a custom setting to the node, but ok, one problem might be that you start this node with a name which already is given to an existent node from your network

Comment: @aurelius, note that `IgnitionEx` is private API, so I don't recommend to use it as it can be changed or removed at any time. Use `Ignition` class instead.